# Overlining text label in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, expression

I would like to know is there anyway to overline a text label like this in ArcGIS10.3.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Try something like:

```
u'\u0305'.join([KOM_KOD])
```

[image]

See: [Make overlines in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33885634/make-overlines-in-python)